# SqlDbType.VarChar Max size reached

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In My Code i am passing `string result` value to my stored procedure

```
try
{
using (SqlStoredProcedure sspObj = new SqlStoredProcedure("dbo.usp_CloseEvent", Connection, CommandType.StoredProcedure))
{
sspObj.AddParameterWithValue("@Close", SqlDbType.VarChar, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, result);
sspObj.ExecuteNonQuery();
sspObj.Dispose();
}
}
catch (Exception xObj)
{
Console.WriteLine("Error >> " + xObj.Message);
}
```

Default `SqlDbType.VarChar` Size is 1 to 8000 characters. My Question is **What if my `string` variable `result` has size more than 8000 characters**

And what is solution for this ?

My Stored Procedure Look like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_CloseEvent]
    @Close      VarChar(Max)
AS
```

SqlStoredProcedure.cs

```
virtual public SqlParameter AddParameterWithValue(string parameterName,
            SqlDbType dbType,
            int size,
            ParameterDirection direction,
            object value) {

            SqlParameter p = this.AddParameter(parameterName, dbType, size, direction);

            if (value == null) {
                value = DBNull.Value;
            }

            p.Value = value;

            return p;
        }
```

Database is SQL SERVER 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a `VARCHAR(MAX)`, you need to pass -1 as the size when adding a parameter.

Comment: Will it Pass More than 8000 Characters From Code to My Stored Procedure When Data Type is SqlDbType.VarChar ?

Comment: Yes, it will - no truncation will be performed if you've specified -1 for the size.

Answer (score 0):

> My questions are:
>   What if my string variable result has size more than 8000 characters?

An error message will occure that says the the input data will be truncated at the end of the string (to truncate means to cut off).

> And what is solution for this?

I think first you check how many characters can be passed to the stored procedure and change the table column manually.

An alternative way is to change the column definition with the SQL command `Alter Table`. But I don't recommend this way

Comment: No alter table needed as i want just the value in my stored procedure which is more than 8000 characters.

Comment: @SagarDumbre You have to check the size of your argumentfirst and then pass it to the SQL command. I can just repeat it. don't do that...